# Azure CSI Key Vault Provider Dynamic Update Secrets while Pod is Online

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

We're using AKS, Azure Key Vaults, and presently use the CSI driver to deliver secret data into our containers (via the CSI driver) at container creation.

The documentation for the CSI driver seems to indicate that it supports dynamic key vault value updates via 'autorotation'.  However, if we take one of our pods that is online and has secrets mounted and change the secret value in the key store, we are not seeing that value change in our pod -- we've waited > 60m to see if there was some kind of polling interval.

Can anyone confirm if CSI Driver key autorotation is supposed to dynamically keep the secrets in running pods up-to-date?  Ultimately, we're looking for a way to refresh our secrets in our pods that come from Azure Key Vaults (via the CSI driver) without incurring a pod reboot.  If anyone could point us in the right direction, we'd be grateful.

Comment: are you retrieving the secrets every time you need them or on start up ?

Comment: Have you configured these as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/kubernetes/tutorial-akv-secrets-provider#additional-configuration-options ?

Comment: @thomas -- I'm not entirely clear how the CSI driver operates but it mounts specific secrets from the keystore on container-creation.  The secrets that get mounted as well as from what key store are all identified in the YAML.  They end up in the container as txt files wiht the names of the files as the names of the secrets.  Each txt file's (aka secret's) file contents if the secret value.

Comment: @Thomas, no, that article is what I was missing.  Please move that to an answer and I'll mark it.  Tyvm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/kubernetes/tutorial-akv-secrets-provider#additional-configuration-options), there are additional configuration you can apply:

> - enableSecretRotation: Boolean type. If `true`, periodically updates the pod mount and Kubernetes Secret with the latest content from external secrets store.
> - rotationPollInterval: Specifies the secret rotation poll interval duration if `enableSecretRotation` is `true`. This duration can be adjusted based on how frequently the mounted contents for all pods and Kubernetes secrets need to be resynced to the latest.
> - syncSecret.enabled: Boolean input. In some cases, you may want to create a Kubernetes Secret to mirror the mounted content. If `true`, `SecretProviderClass` allows the `secretObjects` field to define the desired state of the synced Kubernetes Secret objects.